# titlesec - set top margin for the appendix and bibliography

Tags: spacing, sectioning, bibliographies, appendices, titlesec

A while ago I was helped using titlesec to format the chapter title for my thesis. Today a reviewer says that the appendix and the bibliography need 1in top margin. How do I do it? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[letter, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[breaklinks = true]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{minted}
%\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.5in, right=1.0in]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*{\bibname}}{\chapter*{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}}{}{}

\usepackage{titlesec}
 \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{1in}{20pt}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\centering\normalfont\normalsize}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}{0pt}{\small}

 \titleformat{\section}
     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
 \titleformat{\subsection}
     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
 \titleformat{\subsubsection}
     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\chapter{PROBLEM}
\appendix

\chapter{CODES}
\chapter{LIST OF PUBLICATIONS}

\begin{thebibliography}{100}
\bibitem{Niesen}
Niesen.
\newblock Social networks/blogs now account for one in every four and a half minutes online.
\newblock {\em http://blog.nielsen.com/nielsenwire/global/social-media-accounts-for-22-percent-of-time-online/}.
\newblock (June 2010).
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your example, the space before the appendix chapters and the unnumbered bibliography is the same as for the main chapters (presumably 1in, as you specified in `\titlespacing*`). Should you need a different space starting with the appendix chapters (though that seems inconsistent), issue another `\titlespacing*` immediately after `\appendix` in the document body.

Note that in the "before code" argument of `\titleformat`, *"[t]he very last command can take an argument, which is the title text"* (manual, p. 4). That is, you may use `\MakeUppercase` and do without writing chapter names capitalized. Also note that (within `titlesec` commands) you should replace `\centering` with `\filcenter` to ensure correct left and right spacing.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{1in}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\filcenter\normalfont\normalsize}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}{0pt}
    {\small\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\appendix
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0.5in}{20pt}

\chapter{Codes}

\begin{thebibliography}{100}
\bibitem{Niesen}
Niesen.
\newblock Social networks/blogs now account for one in every four and a half minutes online.
\newblock {\em http://blog.nielsen.com/nielsenwire/global/social-media-accounts-for-22-percent-of-time-online/}.
\newblock (June 2010).
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```